# Javascript String Manipulation - lowercase, replace, trim, split

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I could probably manage this in PHP using preg_replace, but I need to do it in JavaScript, and I'm struggling!

I'll be getting starting strings from a database, for example: -

```
Black Pudding with Eggs
```

or

```
Sausage and Crispy Bacon
```

etc etc. - always 2 "things" split by either an "and" or a "with". The "things" can be 1, 2 or more words.

What I need from these is 3 new variables - both together, and each "thing" individually (with "main" appended to the first thing and "side" appended to the second). All should be lowercase, with any spaces changed to underscores, and no leading or training spaces. So the above would give me: -

```
var1 : 'black_pudding_with_eggs'
var2 : 'black_pudding_main'
var3 : 'eggs_side'
```

and from the 2nd one: -

```
var1 : 'sausage_and_crispy_bacon'
var2 : 'sausage_main'
var3 : 'crispy_bacon_side'
```

The site it's on already uses jQuery so that's an option, if that makes it easier...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: and... what have you tried so far?

Comment: You know what to do, so why not do it?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically create variables at runtime? This will dissolve into an atrocious mess very quickly.

Comment: There are NLP libraries for PHP, I'd try that path. With regex, you can't  tell `I swim and run` from `crispy bacon and eggs`. Also, since you mau have 1 or more words belonging to the main words, regex won't  be able to find the correct phrases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: this appears to be a very specific domain, with well-formatted input strings. One doesn't even need regexes here. Just split on "and" or "with"

Comment: I'll be honest and say I didn't try anything before posting. I knew that anything I tried would be woefully inefficient, as I don't know JavaScript that well.

I knew what to do, not how to do it. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery isn't necessary. You can split the string into an array and convert it using `.replace()`.

```
function getOrder(input) {
    var item = input.replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase();

    // there's probably a better way of splitting this, but I can't think of it.
    var dish = (input.indexOf(' and ') > -1) ? input.split(' and ') : input.split(' with ');

    var main = dish[0].replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase() + "_main";
    var side = dish[1].replace(/ /g, '_').toLowerCase() + "_side";

    // returns a JS object so to have access to all properties in one function
    return {
        item: item,
        main: main,
        side: side
    };
}
```

Then, you can get the parts like this:

`getOrder('Black Pudding with Eggs').item` for `black_pudding_with_eggs`

`getOrder('Black Pudding with Eggs').main` for `black_pudding_main`

`getOrder('Black Pudding with Eggs').side` for `eggs_side`

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/tujdb98y/

Note that this method expects " and " or " with " in the input, otherwise things break. Can be easily modified to accommodate for those if necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It works very well, except that you were spot on with your final comment....if there's no side, nothing is returned at all. I do need to account for this possibility, e.g. just "Sausage", resulting in "sausage" and also "sausage_main", but no side.

Comment: The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/tujdb98y/) was updated to accommodate for no sides. You can change the `side = 'none'` to set a default, or just remove the ` = 'none'` to leave it out entirely. I'm using regex to determine whether there is a side, but you can also do something like `input.indexOf(' and ') > -1 && input.indexOf(' with ') > -1`.

Comment: Thanks also to @Icepickle - your solution also did exactly what I needed!

Comment: Some forward slashes have appeared causing issues - I tried adding them to the replace, escaping them, but it didn't work: 

    var main = dish[0].replace(/ \//g, '_').toLowerCase() + "_main";

Comment: The change you made actually causes it to look for the literal string of " /" (with a space). You need to use RegExp to match a set of characters, and this can be done by using `/[ /]/g`. Btw, the replace is technically already using RegExp, but only for the `g` flag to make it a global replace. I updated the JSFiddle above to demonstrate this behavior. The RegExp was moved to a separate variable for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no need for regex or anything special. If you have such clear strings, you can do it like this ( the third string in the example can be a bit more problematic :) )

I commented the code a bit, but if you need more info feel free to ask

```js
'use strict';
var input1 = 'Black Pudding with Eggs',
  input2 = 'Sausage and Crispy Bacon',
  input3 = 'Steak with colliflower and fries';

function getSplittedText(input) {
  if (!input || !input.toLowerCase) {
    // no text or not a string
    return null;
  }
  // make it lowercase, and replace all spaces with underscore
  var parsed = input.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),
    splitWith = '_with_',
    results = [parsed]; // add the parsed text to the array
  
  // in case the sentence has _and_ in it, use _and_ to split the text
  if (parsed.indexOf('_and_') >= 0) {
    splitWith = '_and_';
  }
  // split the text with either _and_ or _with_ and add the results to the array
  parsed.split( splitWith ).forEach(function(item, i) {
    results.push(item + (i == 0 ? '_main' : '_side')); // if it's 0, it will be main, if not it will be a side
  });
  return results;
}

console.log(getSplittedText(input1));
console.log(getSplittedText(input2));
// this one is a bit tricky, probably you might have to think about better ones...
console.log(getSplittedText(input3));
```

Answer (score 0):

This method accepts strings without 'and' or 'with' in input. 
It also properly treats phrases that contain 'and' or 'with' in the words. For eg, s**and**wich ,**with**al

```
function parseString(string) 
{
    string      = string.trim().replace(/ /g,'_').toLowerCase();//replace spaces with _ and convert to lowercase 
    var parts   = string.split('_with_')[0] === string? string.split('_and_') : string.split('_with_');  
    if(parts[0] === string)//if there's NO 'with' or 'and' in the string
    {    
        return {
            together: string,
            main:  ``, 
            side:  ``  
        };
    }   
    return {//if there's a 'with' or 'and' in the string
        together: string,
        main:  `${parts[0]}_main`, 
        side:  `${parts[1]}_side`  
    };  
}
```

Please use like so:

```
Example 1: 
var result = parseString('Sausage and Crispy Bacon'); 
//result.together outputs 'sausage_and_crispy_bacon'
//result.main outputs      'sausage_main'
//result.side outputs      'crispy_bacon_side'

Example 2: 
var result = parseString('Black Pudding with Eggs'); 
//result.together outputs 'black_pudding_with_eggs'
//result.main outputs     'black_pudding_main'
//result.side outputs     'eggs_side'

Example 2: 
var result = parseString(''Sunshine Sandwiches Withal''); 
//result.together outputs 'sunshine_sandwiches_withal'
//result.main outputs     ''
//result.side outputs     ''
```